# Dividing NetLogo world into two parts

Tags: network-analysis

I'm working with NetLogo now and I have to divide my 'world' into two parts. As you can see in the picture, my world is already divided into two parts by the river. However, my turtles still cross the river as if they can walk on water. Does someone know what I have to do to make sure the turtles can't cross the river anymore and can only stay on their own side?

[image: NetLogo]

Comment: silly question: Don't turtles swim?

Comment: Turtle is just the name of the agents in the model

Answer (score 1):

This code I got from a model in netlogo called, Many Region Example which might help you. Basically what it is doing is that it is restricting turtles to enter another regions.

```
to keep-in-region [ which-region ] ; turtle procedure

  ; This is the procedure that make sure that turtles don't leave the region they're
  ; supposed to be in. It is your responsibility to call this whenever a turtle moves.
  if region != which-region [
    ; Get our region boundaries from the global region list:
    let region-min-pxcor first item (which-region - 1) region-boundaries
    let region-max-pxcor last item (which-region - 1) region-boundaries
    ; The total width is (min - max) + 1 because `pxcor`s are in the middle of patches:
    let region-width (region-max-pxcor - region-min-pxcor) + 1
    ifelse xcor < region-min-pxcor [ ; if we crossed to the left,
      set xcor xcor + region-width   ; jump to the right boundary
    ] [
      if xcor > region-max-pxcor [   ; if we crossed to the right,
        set xcor xcor - region-width ; jump to the left boundary
      ]
    ]
  ]

end
```